# AVPlayerItem removeObserver:forKeyPath get error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
   if (mPlayerItem){
    [mPlayerItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:kStatusKey];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                  object:mPlayerItem];
}

//create AVPlayerItem
NSURL *url = [self getUrlWithROAudio:audioFile];

mPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
[mPlayerItem    addObserver:self
                forKeyPath:kStatusKey
                options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                context:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:mPlayerItem];
```

when i create a new AVPlayerItem , i will check if last one is exist, and removeObserver
but i got
       -[AVPlayerItem removeObserver:forKeyPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance

anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point, the object pointed to by `mPlayerItem` is being released, but `mPlayerItem` is not being set to `nil`. Look for places where you may be under-retaining or over-releasing your player instances.

Comment: if mPlayerItem is nil or released , will it pass if (mPlayerItem)?

Comment: if i dont removemPlayerItem's Observer and add new one for same keypath . is it ok?

Comment: If the object pointed to by `mPlayerItem` has been released, it will still pass the nil check, causing this exception. This is one of the gotchas of manual reference count management.

Comment: thanks warrenm, but if so how can i know if this object han been released ro not?

Comment: i release mPlayerItem,and set it to nil, before i create a new one,and for now it fixed my problem

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you have a single place where you release your `AVPlayerItem` instances, you could try removing your observers immediately before releasing the player items. This might help ensure everything gets cleaned up correctly. Also, will you mark this answer as accepted so other people can find it in the future?